# Loop through Jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, loops

I have this script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
// run the currently selected effect
function runEffect() {
  // get effect type from
  var selectedEffect = $( "#Puff" ).val();

  // most effect types need no options passed by default
  var options = {};
  // some effects have required parameters
  if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
    options = { percent: 0 };
  } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
    options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
  }

  // run the effect
  $( "#myModal" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );
  };

 // set effect from select menu value
 $( "div.notAMember a" ).click(function() {
  runEffect();
  });
  });

  $(function() {
  // run the currently selected effect
  function runEffect() {
  // get effect type from
  var selectedEffect = $( "#Puff" ).val();

  // most effect types need no options passed by default
  var options = {};
  // some effects have required parameters
  if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
    options = { percent: 0 };
  } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
    options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
  }

  // run the effect
  $( "#myModalJoin" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );
  };

   // set effect from select menu value
   $( "div.registeredMember a" ).click(function() {
  runEffect();
  });
  });

 </script>
```

It's purpose is that when a modal is open and i click a link in it, the modal closes and a new modal is shown. I want to click a link now in the new modal and when doing so, close the open modal and open the first modal again.
How can i loop through this modals by clicking a link on each one of them?

Comment: HTML code please, some of your selectors are a bit vague without it.

Comment: it sounds like a wizard a little bit... right ?

Comment: Here is the full HTML/PHP code: https://jsfiddle.net/6ka625pL/

Comment: Is there any way you could refine your Fiddle to show only the parts necessary to your issue? Since JSFiddle doesn't support PHP, simply dumping your code, PHP and all, into it isn't very helpful.

Comment: Thank you IronFlare, Thank you, Currently on my way to work, so I will do so in the evening and update

Comment: Hi IronFlare, I update my Fiddle. Can you take a look and advise?
Thanks

Comment: Hi IronFlare, any suggestions?